# How to give inputs and output responses not using dialogflow in a chatbot?

Tags: json, nlp, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am developing a chatbot using dialogflow for a website.

1)I wanted to know if there is other way to give inputs and output responses  not using dailogflow platform , as the login is mine in the dialogflow and the officials want to use that chatbot for their site and put their inputs and outputs.

2)Can the conversation be stored in some mysql database other than storing in the history of dialogflow application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow doesn't "compile" to anything else, so it needs to be run on the Dialogflow servers. You can, however, export the project and the officials can create their own project and import it.

If you are using webhook fulfillment, then you can log anything you wish using the fulfillment's code. If you are just using the responses entered in Dialogflow, then no, you can't do any outside logging.

Comment: If this answers your question, upvoting and/or accepting the answer are appreciated. If you have further questions - asking them as new StackOver questions is appropriate.